# How can I JOIN the ARRAY results of this formula with a ","?

Tags: join, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I've tried to add `JOIN` to this formula in every place I can think of, but none seem to be correct.

```excel
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D&E2:E, 
 TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 {INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D))*(LEN(tasksAssociations!G2:G)), 
 tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D&"♦"&tasksAssociations!G2:G, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),,1), IF(
 ISNUMBER(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D))*(LEN(tasksAssociations!G2:G)), 
 tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D&"♦"&tasksAssociations!G2:G, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0)),
 QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D))*(LEN(tasksAssociations!G2:G)), 
 tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D&"♦♥"&tasksAssociations!G2:G, )), 1, 1), "♦")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 limit 0", 0), )})
 ,,999^99))), "♥"))), {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}, 0)))
```

The results are multiple columns/rows.  I want to keep the rows, but `JOIN` the column values with a "`,`".

[my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-FdpxsNcrqXXWroYzeAQZz5TuyEX6xKnTif0rrrJl60/edit#gid=274711828&range=Z2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this perhaps:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D&E2:E, 
 TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 {INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D))*(LEN(tasksAssociations!G2:G)), 
 tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D&"♦"&tasksAssociations!G2:G, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),,1), IF(
 ISNUMBER(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D))*(LEN(tasksAssociations!G2:G)), 
 tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D&"♦"&tasksAssociations!G2:G, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0)),
 QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D))*(LEN(tasksAssociations!G2:G)), 
 tasksAssociations!C2:C&tasksAssociations!D2:D&"♦♥"&tasksAssociations!G2:G, )), 1, 1), "♦")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 limit 0", 0), )})
 ,,999^99))), "♥"))), {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}, 0)), " ", "♫")),,999^99))), " ", ", "), "♫", " "))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I see you wrapped it in three `SUBSTITUTE`s.  I understand how one of them replace spaces with `"♫"` and then back again.  What is the logic here?  Obviously necessary, but doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: query smash (eg: `TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(...),,999^99))`) joins all columns into 1 column and each of those columns are separated with extra space (eg: col1value col2value col3value ...) but we need comma+space as separator so all spaces in dataset before query smash are replaced with unique symbol, then query smash joins all columns with just space separator. then we replace space separator with comma+space and then get back all original spaces before smash by replacing unique symbol with space